# Show all tables inside a MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to show all the tables in my database. I've tried this:

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$tables = $result->fetch_assoc();
foreach($tables as $tmp)
{
    echo "$tmp <br>";
}
```

but it only gives me one table name in a database I know has 2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

## How to get tables

### 1. `SHOW TABLES`

```
mysql> USE test;
Database changed
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| t1             |
| t2             |
| t3             |
+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### 2. `SHOW TABLES IN db_name`

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES IN another_db;
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_another_db |
+----------------------+
| t3                   |
| t4                   |
| t5                   |
+----------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### 3. Using information schema

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME
       FROM information_schema.TABLES
       WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'another_db';
+------------+
| TABLE_NAME |
+------------+
| t3         |
| t4         |
| t5         |
+------------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

## to OP

you have fetched just 1 row. fix like this:

```
while ( $tables = $result->fetch_array())
{
    echo $tmp[0]."<br>";
}
```

and I think, information_schema would be better than `SHOW TABLES`

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your database name'

while ( $tables = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo $tables['TABLE_NAME']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: or `SHOW TABLES IN DB_MANE`

Comment: There is no reason not to use `SHOW TABLES` unless the active connection is making use of temporary tables.

Comment: @holodoc that's my personal opinion. title of `SHOW TABLE`'s output is something like `'Tables_in_TBL_NAME'`. so when executed in client program. So column name is changed. and people don't know about information_schema which has more useful information about DB

Comment: Perfect. For some reason I thought that it'd just return an array of the actual tables, not rows.

Comment: I like Solution #3 the best. The `information_schema.tables` table gives me a lot more info. Always nice to look into

Comment: Minor point for future readers: changing `$tables` to `$table` might help clarify that each row contains information about *one* table. I realize the name was just copied from the question, but might as well correct OP's confusion about what is returned. Or use a traditional name such as `$row`.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM nameOfDatabase;
```

Answer (score 2):

SHOW TABLE_NAME is not valid. Try SHOW TABLES

TD

Comment: Whoops, meant to change that. I was testing different things and just copy-pasted from my code. It was SHOW TABLES

Answer (score 0):

SHOW TABLES only lists the non-TEMPORARY tables in a given database.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$dbname = 'mysql_dbname';
if (!mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')) {
echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
exit;
}
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
//Try This code is running perfectly !!!!!!!!!!
```

---

---

Comment: This is just a code snippet. If it's an actual answer, then it should have some explanation as to how it works and why it's a better answer than the other ones.

Comment: I found this useful as a quick snippet to experiment with. Thanks amit!