# Get mysql database schema

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to get the full structure of a mySQL database in json or xml format?

what I'm looking for is a way to get the schema (stored data doesn't matter) to use it to create a backend/crud for the application.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a fully comprehensive answer to the question, as it doesn't return a json. But it's a simple class that gives all relevant info about a table as an object. This could easily be transformed to return a json.

The class relies on having passed a db object that implements a `rawQuery` method, as [PHP-Mysqli-Database-Class](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class) does. But you could easily rewrite the method `extractTableInfo` if you need.

```
<?php
Class dbHelper {
    private $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function extractTableInfo($tableName) {
        $result = $this->db->rawQuery("DESCRIBE `".$tableName."`");

        $tableInfo = array();
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            $info = new \stdClass();
            $info->name = $value['Field'];
            $info->type = $this->_getColumnType($value['Type']);
            $info->length = $this->_getLength($value['Type']);
            $info->hasNull = $this->_getNull($value['Null']);
            $info->default = $this->_getDefault($value['Default']);
            $tableInfo[] = $info;
        }
        return $tableInfo;
    }

    public function getIndexes($tableName) {
        $result = $this->db->rawQuery("SHOW INDEX FROM `".$tableName."`");
        return $result;
    }



    private function _getLength($info) {
        $pattern = '/\({1}([\d\W]*)\){1}/';
        preg_match($pattern, $info, $matches);
        return isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : NULL;
    }

    private function _getColumnType($info) {
        $pattern = '/([\w]*)(\([\d\W]*\))*/';
        preg_match($pattern, $info, $matches);
        return isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : NULL;
    }

    private function _getNull($info) {
        if($info==='NO') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private function _getDefault($info) {
        if($info>='') {
            return $info;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
$db = YOUR DATABASE OBJECT/CLASS;
$dbHelper = new dbHelper($db);
$tableName = "test";
$tableInfo = $dbHelper->extractTableInfo($tableName);
echo json_encode($tableInfo);
```

To get a list of all tables in a database you'll need:

```
SHOW TABLES [in dbname]
```

or follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183553/show-all-tables-inside-a-mysql-database)

Still, there are many alternatives with different benefits/outputs:

- using [mysql workbench](https://www.mysql.com/de/products/workbench/)
- using phpmyadmin
- using command line `mysqldump -u root -p --no-data dbname > schema.sql`

Comment: Thanks! this is some advanced php code!! I'll try to make it work. thanks again (i'll need some time to try and customize it then i'll mark your answer "accepted")

Comment: Feel free to ask further questions if you need!